# Philodendron (Philodendron bipinnatifidum maybe?) is turning into liquid

Tags: leaves, philodendron

[image]I just got a Philodendron (Philodendron bipinnatifidum maybe?) and the plant was beautiful and lush and within a day of me getting it home it looked like it was rotten. Some of the leaves got brown and liquified and some of the leaves turned translucent. I have never seen this happen before. Can anyone help me? Thanks so much!![image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you live in an area where it is currently late winter, and given the looks of the leaves and the fact that the plant's collapse occurred within hours of your getting it home, I'd say that the plant has undergone a large temperature swing during its trip to your house - in fact, the "liquid" and translucent leaves possibly indicate that it froze.

According to [The Ultimate Care Guide](https://www.evergreenseeds.com/philodendron-bipinnatifidum/) for that plant

> Philodendron bipinnatifidum can survive outdoors as long as temperatures don’t drop below 55 °F (13 °C). The plant is not tolerant to frost, which will wilt the leaves and damage the roots. Older, well-established plants might survive cool temperatures during winter.
>
> As long as the roots have not been damaged by frost, your Philodendron should develop new growth in spring. However, it’s best to note that repeated exposure to temperatures below 55 °F (13 °C) will stress the plant. It might not make a successful recovery the following year.